# Bash regex treated as a string not as regex

Tags: regex, bash

Could someone please explain why the following bash code will echo "choice was a number!" when I type e.g. "1" at the read prompt:

```
  read choice
  re='^[0-9]+$'

  if [[ $choice =~ $re ]]; then
    echo "choice was a number!"
  else
    echo "choice was NOT a number!"
  fi
```

... but the same code without the intermediate `$re` variable will echo "choice was NOT a number!":

```
  read choice

  if [[ $choice =~ '^[0-9]+$' ]]; then
    echo "choice was a number!"
  else
    echo "choice was NOT a number!"
  fi
```

?

Comment: Maybe because of the `'`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put the right side of `=~` in quotation marks, then right side will be treated like a string and not like a regex.

Comment: You can force `=~` to ignore the quotes by `shopt -s compat31`.